# Can't override onAuthenticationSuccess method of AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.5

Following some other posts, I tried to override the authentication success method of the spring-security handler, but it's never being called. My code looks like:

`src/groovy/mypackage/MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler.groovy`:

```
package mypackage

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler

import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        println("constructed!")
    }
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        println("override called")
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

resources.groovy:

```
authenticationSuccessHandler(MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    requestCache = ref('requestCache')
    defaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl
    alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl = conf.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault
    targetUrlParameter = conf.successHandler.targetUrlParameter
    useReferer = conf.successHandler.useReferer
    redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
}
```

There are no errors, the constructor is definitely called and `MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is injected into a test controller, but `onAuthenticationSuccess` is never called. I dropped a breakpoint into the superclass version and that worked. I also tried rewriting my custom class in java but that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I'm also using Mitre connect OIDC filter and I think that's subverting spring dependency injection. It calls `this.passthrough.onAuthenticationSuccess` instead of `super.onAuthenticationSuccess` as would have expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out another login filter was already active and it was preventing the normal method from working. The filter in question is `org.mitre.openid.connect.client.OIDCAuthenticationFilter` and the workaround is to inject your success handler through that one e.g.:

```
    authenticationSuccessHandler(apipulse.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
        clientRegistrationTemplate = ref(clientRegistrationTemplate)
    }

    ...

    openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter(OIDCAuthenticationFilter) {
        ...
        authenticationSuccessHandler = ref('authenticationSuccessHandler')
    }
```

Just wasted a day looking at this - thanks a bunch, spring.